# Grow a shape in the Euclidean plane (or space) by adding unit boxes to the surface at random places. Do we get an almost-ball almost-certainly?

Tags: stochastic-processes, integer-lattices

I hope my title asks the question reasonably well, but I'll add some rigor here.  Consider a process as follows: at step $ n = 0 $ we start with a set consisting of one point, $ S_0 = \{(0,0)\} $.  For each $ n \geq 1 $ we compute $ S_n $ as follows.  Let $ T_{n-1} $ denote the "lattice boundary" of $ S_{n-1} $, i.e., the set of lattice points which are "adjacent" to points in $ S_{n-1} $ *but not in* $ S_{n-1} $.  For example $ T_0 = \{(1,0), (0,1), (-1,0), (0,-1)\} $.  Now $ S_n $ is constructed by adding adding exactly one uniformly-randomly-chosen point from $ T_{n-1} $ to $ S_{n-1} $.

I thought of this today while playing Carcassonne, in which the game board mimics this process (kind of).  The board seemed to be roughly a ball at the end.

**Conjecture**: For large $ n $, $ S_n $ is almost-certainly nearly (the set of lattice points inside) the *Euclidean* ball of volume $ n $ centered about the origin.

**Stronger (and more dubious) Conjecture**: An analogous statement is true if we run an analogous process in the $ m $-dimensional lattice $ \mathbb{Z}^m $ for any dimension $ m $.

I believe the use of "almost certainly nearly" is going to be understood by most readers, but I can elaborate on a definition with some epsilons and deltas if too many readers are head-scratching.

**Question for readers**: Do you have proofs or ideas for proofs or ideas why either conjecture might be false?  I am surprised this question was not easily found by my Google search or stack exchange search.  It seems quite natural.

**My thoughts** My mathematician friend thought that the "large surface area phenomenon" in high dimensions might give rise to "highly branching" non-ball-like shapes in high dimensions, but we agreed it's probably true when $ m = 2 $.  If I had to bet, I'd say the stronger conjecture is also true though.

A picture for $ m = 2 $, $ n = 10,000 $ with superimposed sphere of radius $ \sqrt{10000/\pi} $
[[image: A picture for <span class=]$ m = 2 $, $ n = 10,000 $ with superimposed sphere of radius $ \sqrt{10000/\pi} $" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkhCX.png)